# Is oneline namespaces on one line with clang-format possible?

Tags: c++, llvm, clang-format

Is there a way to get clang-format to put oneline namespaces on one line like below? I need to do some forward declarations and I prefere to put it like this.

```
namespace One {
    namespace Two { class MyClassA; }
    namespace Two { typedef std::unique_ptr<MyClassA> MyClassAUPtr; }

    namespace Two { class MyClassB; }
    namespace Two { typedef std::unique_ptr<MyClassB> MyClassBUPtr; }

    namespace Three { class MyClassC; }
    namespace Three { typedef std::unique_ptr<MyClassC> MyClassCUPtr; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as of [clang-format 13](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), there is no such option.

Comment: Right. Is it possible to write custom regex with a function with clang-format? I guess I could turn off clang-format on those lines..

Comment: @TLoe Sure, if you turn clang-format off and use a different formatter, anything is possible.

Comment: I didn't mean to use another formatter though, but using the "// clang-format off" "// clang-format on" functionality of clang-format and wrap my forward declaration.. And the other question was if clang-format has a implementation for writing custom regex expressions to recognize some patterns and then doing an operation on that code and normal formatting wont run on that part of the code.

Comment: Just realized its possible to write namespace One::Two {} from c++17.. then I might be happy with organizing it a bit differntly :) been away from c++ for a while..

Comment: @TLoe Yes, and you can also use the more modern `using MyClassAUPtr = std::unique_ptr<MyClassA>;` to create `typedef`s.

Comment: "_the other question was if clang-format has a implementation for writing custom regex expressions to recognize some patterns and then doing an operation on that code and normal formatting wont run on that part of the code_" - Not that I know of but you could ask a new question about that to make sure.

Comment: Thanks.. accepting  your answer as it answer my question :)

Comment: @TLoe You're welcome and I hope you find a workaround.